# How to disable next button in msi if Dialog textbox has invalid/no value?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

I have a Text Box in MSI Project and I want to validate whether it is Filled or Empty

if empty next button has to be in disable state else it has to continue.how to do this

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer has a table called the [ControlCondition table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Using this table you can create conditions that Enable, Disable, Hide and/or Show a control.  However, the tool you are using doesn't expose this underlying feature of Windows Installer.  This is one of the many, many reasons Visual Studio Deployment Projects were removed from Visual Studio 2010.

There are hack ways of using postbuild events to run SQL commands against the built MSI to inject the functionality but I don't recommend this.  It's like tweaking the MSIL of a built assembly because C# didn't support something that CLR could do.

Answer (score 0):

just google `orca table editor` and download this tool using this you can view the database that @Christopher is talking about. You can do this by right clicking on the MSI that is generated after building your project and `open with` the  `Orca editor` you will be given access to the entire database and please make sure you change the table mentioned by Christopher care fully as there is little or no validation when you make changes to this table.

Comment: But this is a one time thing if the project is built again using visual studio changes made by you using this editor will be lost so better write sql scripts in the post build event your project.

Comment: yep i read about that already...i will use Installshield... :) thanks for suggestion :)